# Trouble getting mapping to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3.0.5.  None of my annotated controllers are getting recognized.  I have XML for my application …

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"/> 
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myco.systems.leadsmonitor"/>
```

My static assets are getting picked up fine.  But I'm getting a 404 when I try and reach an annotated controller …

```
package com.myco.systems.leadsmonitor.web.controller;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    …

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("latestLeadTime", MonitorStatistics.getInstance().getLatestLeadCreationTime());
        model.addAttribute("lastDBCheck", MonitorStatistics.getInstance().getLastDBCheck());
    }
```

What else do I need to do to get my controllers picked up by Spring?  Thanks, - Dave

Comment: What is the URL pattern that you use for the Spring DispatcherServlet in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are getting a 404 is because the view is not being resolved in the contoller method. By default a void return type is mapped using to a view name based on the URI, in your case since the path is "/", it probably gets resolved to "", which does not get mapped to any logical view.

Can you try a couple of things:

1. Start in a debug mode and see if your request is actually coming to the RequestMapping method
2. If it is, can you explicitly return a view name from your method and see if this view name is getting resolved to a correct view(assuming that you have a view resolver registered)

Answer (score 0):

You should check both URL mappings in web.xml and view resolution configuration in your spring configuration.

One good resource is Spring By Example.org

see: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-mvc-form-annotation-config-webapp.html

Another one are the tutorials available in SpringSource ToolSuite (STS), where they walk you through creating a Spring MVC web application.  Those tutorials usually include the UrlRewriteFilter from tuckey.org

e.g. servlet maps to /app, then add this servlet filter

```
<!-- Enables clean URLs with JSP views e.g. /welcome instead of /app/welcome -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
<!--        <init-param>-->
<!--            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>-->
<!--            <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>-->
<!--        </init-param>-->

</filter>
```